# Testing an MP3 with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, mp3

I want to set up a testing routine in Phantom that scans a podcast RSS feed, grabs the URLs of MP3 files, then tests to see that they exist. I have this:

```
/* For checking one mp3 file */
function checkFile(url) {  
    var fs = require('fs');

    if (fs.exists(url)) {
        console.log('"'+url+'" exists.');
    } else {
        console.log('"'+url+'" doesn\'t exist.');
    }
}

/* For checking the whole feed */
page.open('/path/to/rss/', function(status) {
    if (status === 'fail') {
        console.log(status);
    } else {
        var content = page.content;
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content,'text/xml');
        var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('item');
        console.log('Feed contains ' + item.length + ' items');

        var enclosures = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('enclosure');
        for(var i=0; i < enclosures.length; i++) 
        {
            var enclosureAttributes = enclosures[i].attributes;
            var url = enclosureAttributes.getNamedItem("url").value;
            console.log('Checking: ' + url);
            checkFile(url);
        }
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

However the fs.exists() function always returns false. The MP3 files download directly in the browser instead of playing, so maybe that's the problem. Or maybe it's not allowing enough time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fs module like name says is a file system module. You can't access remote files with it.

You will either have use `page.open()` and see what status is passed into the callback (it's asynchronous: can't use a loop here). Or you can use a non-async `XMLHttpRequest` inside of `page.evaluate()` (you will have to run PhantomJS with `--web-security=false` if the files are on another domain).

Comment: With `page.open()` I just get a 'fail' status every time.

Comment: Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Thanks. `onResourceReceived` was useful in the end, as the first header was 'Moved Permanently'. I'll need to loop through the headers to find "audio/mpeg" then get the status of that.